# Android Custom Dialog not showing after onRequestedPermissionResult

Tags: android, dialog, gps, android-permissions, locationmanager

In my application I am requesting the location permission from user. When user allow the location permission then I check if GPS is enabled or not. If GPS is not available then it should show a custom dialog. But the problem is dialog not showing right after allow. I have checked with debugger it goes through the code of dialog but it doesn't show the dialog.

```
/**
     * show LocationRequestDialog to enable location
     */
    public void showEnableLocatioAlert(final Context mContext, int id) {
        mLocationDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        mAppData.mDialogsList.add(mLocationDialog);
        mLocationDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mLocationDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        mLocationDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mLocationDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_internet_not_avail);
        TextView titleTV = (TextView) mLocationDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitleTV);
        TextView bodyTV = (TextView) mLocationDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogMessageTV);
        titleTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.gps_disabled));
        bodyTV.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.enable_gps));
        Button yesBT = (Button) mLocationDialog.findViewById(R.id.yesBT);
        Button noBT = (Button) mLocationDialog.findViewById(R.id.noBT);
        yesBT.setText(getString(R.string.enable));
        noBT.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
        yesBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yesBT.requestLayout();
        noBT.requestLayout();

        final Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);
        yesBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLocationDialog.dismiss();
                mAppData.isSettingsOrGalleryOpened = true;
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);

            }
        });
        noBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLocationDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        mLocationDialog.show();
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.LOCATION_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //locateMe();
                showEnableLocatioAlert(getActivity(), R.id.containerFL);
            } else {
                Utils.getInstance().showPermissionDialog(getActivity(), mView, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please show `Constants.LOCATION_PERMISSIONS`

Comment: @SergeyShustikov its just a request code

Comment: I think problem is here mLocationDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        mLocationDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));            just remove above code for a while and test it